# With SQL, how do I deal with JOINing databases with a lot of columns that all need to be unique?

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, large-files

Okay so this is the first time I'm working with a big database and it's quite scary.
This is an example what I want to have happen:

Tables

```
table 1
ID   art1  art2
1    90    20
2    20    80
3    20    20

table 2
ID   art1  art2
1    20    20
2    40    30
4    20    50
```

Desired Result (order doesn't matter)

```
table 1
ID   art1  art2
1    ...
2
3
4
```

I kind of get that in a small scale, I use LEFT JOIN for this, and from what I read, GROUP BY for at least the attributes (if not the ID?).

My problem is that these tables are huge. There is 30 or more columns and about 25k rows.

So am I expected to write 30+ GROUP BYs? Isn't there something more efficient? Like GROUP ALL?

There is also a weird thing about these tables. They have a lof of Null rows (that have attr 1 in some columns), and they all have ID of 0. But they have to stay there as the table, for functional reasons, has to have exactly 26001 rows. So after I'm done I have to shave off as many rows as I've added, but I can't do that outside of SQL as well as that's faster for me.

Also is my thinking even correct? So far I've tried only one query, before I found out about GROUP BY. I waited 5 minutes for about half a million rows, so that wasn't good. My query was:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table1` 
LEFT JOIN `table2`
USING (ID)
```

And now I'm thinking it should be

```
SELECT *
FROM `table1` 
LEFT JOIN `table2`
USING (ID)
GROUP BY *insert all columns?*
```

But I'm not sure, do I also have to "line up" all the columns to not get repeated results? Or do I have to use DISTINCT? On all 30+ columns again?

Answer (score 0):

considering other comments and answers, my suggestion is:

1. Use `SELECT *` with caution, usually it will query everything including things that you don't need. Since BigQuery is colunar, it will increase billing of the query the same way you increase the number of columns. Take your case into consideration here.
2. If you want to give `join` another try, consider using `inner join` for your case, because it will filter out what you doesn't want, and it performs better than the `where` clause at the end, considering the big data scenario, that's a win.
3. `UNION` can be a great solution, even if you have already tested. To address your concerns about data duplicity: BigQuery will consider all columns. So if your ID is duplicated but has different data, you will have to specify which is the correct one. To do that, consider:

   1. using a [window function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/window-function-calls) to do the row count using [row_number() function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#row_number). Window functions performs better than group by ones in the big data scenario.
   2. make sure you add all the conditions to identify uniqueness on the `partition by` of the window. Also, a good way to do this is to order as DESC, so the first record is the one you want.
   3. once you have done that, you can filter them using the 0. Every record that has the row number equals to zero is unique and is the one you want.

Window functions are very useful in the big data scenario, and [here](https://medium.com/@sonradata/window-function-rows-and-range-on-redshift-and-bigquery-132cbf80c656) there is a magnificent article to understand that better.